# Is there something like django debug-toolbar for Playframework?

Tags: django, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, profiler

To profile the performance for database querying and CPU time, a debug-toolbar is very useful.. However, I didn't find such thing in Playframework..

Does anyone have ideas about the profiler and debug-toolbar for Playframework?

Comment: I think the closest is something like [xrebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/xrebel/)